# Show that the right shift operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, orthonormal

Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis in $ℓ^2$. Show that $S_{e_n}=e_{n+1}$ defines a bounded linear operator $S: ℓ^2 \rightarrow ℓ^2$ and that $||S||=1$.

Well, I need to show that $||S_{e_n}||_{ℓ^2} \leq C||e_n||_{ℓ^2}$ for a positive constant $C$. I know the definition of the $ℓ^2$-norm but I don't see how it could help me. All the other proofs I have looked for don't use the norm definition. But how could I prove this?

Comment: Here's what the right shift operator does: It takes a sequence $x := (x_1, \ldots)$ and sends it to $S(x) =(0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$. Take the $\ell^2$ norm of $S(x)$, what do you get?